# Writing data to PVirtualNode without setting each field value manually

Tags: delphi, pointers, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Lets say I have this node data record:

```
Type
  PPerson = ^TPerson;
  TPerson = record
   Name: String;
   Age: Integer;
   SomeBool: Boolean;
  end;
```

To populate my VirtualStringTree, I would do this:

```
Procedure AddToTree(Person: TPerson);
Var
 Node: PVirtualNode;
 Data: PPerson;
Begin
 Node := VT.AddChild(nil);
 Data := VT.GetNodeData(Node);
 Data.Name := Person.Name;
 Data.Age  := Person.Age;
 Data.SomeBool := Person.SomeBool;
End;

Procedure TMyForm.MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
 Person: TPerson;
Begin
 Person.Name := 'Jeff';
 Person.Age := 16;
 Person.SomeBool := False;
 AddToTree(Person);

End:
```

Now, while this works perfectly fine, I would like to simplify it, so whenever I add new fields to the record, I wont have modify the AddToTree method.

So I tried this:

```
Procedure AddToTree(Person: TPerson);
Begin
 VT.AddChild(nil,@Person);
End;
```

This compiles, **but** it appears the `PVirtualNode` did not get the data, because my VT is not displaying anything, and when breaking in the OnGetText event, I see the variables are empty.

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Is Person allocated on the stack? Does the tree view take a copy of the data?

Comment: I wonder why the downvote? Seems a valid question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Records support the assignment operator:

```
procedure AddToTree(const Person: TPerson);
var
  Node: PVirtualNode;
  Data: PPerson;
begin
  Node := VT.AddChild(nil);
  Data := VT.GetNodeData(Node);
  Data^ := Person;
end;
```

Comment: Works like a charm! So, what we are doing here, is dereferencing the Data-pointer, so we got a plain record that we can assign to?

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely going to help me! :)

Comment: @Rob How does the reference counting work with this? I'm specifically thinking about the `Data^ := Person` line. That presumably increments ref counts. There needs to be a balancing `Dispose` somewhere to decrement it, right?

Comment: @David, `Dispose` balances `New`, but we're not calling `New`, so there's nothing else to do. The RTL knows how to assign records; it just assigns each field. See `_CopyRecord` in *System.pas*.

Comment: @Rob Right, `GetNodeData` knows the size of the record so it does a GetMem to allocate the space. I thought we need a balancing `Dispose` to call `Finalize` and then free the record's memory. But VST will do the free which leaves the `Finalize`. That must happen sometime, presumably invoked by VST just before it calls `Free` on the data memory. I guess there is a hook, `OnFreeNode` perhaps.

Comment: Yes, @David. If the node data contains any compiler-managed types (like TPerson here does), then the OnFreeNode event needs to call Finalize: `begin Data := Sender.GetNodeData(Node); Finalize(Data^); end;`. The memory for the node data is part of the same allocation as the TVirtualNode itself, so there's nothing additional to free.

Comment: @Rob - In the `OnFreeNode`, I usually do like `Data.Name := '';` for all strings, is that even necessary?

Comment: You *can* set each compiler-managed field to its empty value, but that goes against the stated goal of this question, which was a way to handle the whole data record at once, even if you add new fields. `Finalize` handles the whole record, no matter how many more string, dynamic-array, interface, or variant fields you might eventually add.

Comment: @Rob - So basically, Finalize does the flushing for me?

Comment: Flushing? No. `Finalize` doesn't cause files to be closed or buffers to be cleared. It causes compiler-managed types to be cleaned up. That means strings and dynamic arrays have their reference counts decremented, which may lead to their being freed. Variants are cleared, so if they refer to dynamically allocated memory, that will get freed. Interfaces will have their `Release` methods called, which might end up freeing the underlying object. Before you call `Finalize`, you should do whatever other cleanup you would normally do in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't reading the manual :)

OK, in this case the source is the manual - quote from the `AddChild()` source:

> UserData can be used to set the first 4 bytes of the user data area to an initial value which can be used
>   in OnInitNode and will also cause to trigger the OnFreeNode event (if <> nil) even if the node is not yet
>   "officially" initialized.

IOW it isn't meant to be used in the way youre using it / expecting it to work.

BTW why do you copy data around? Why not have

```
type
  PTreeData = ^TTreeData;
  TTreeData = record
   Data: PPerson;
  end;
```

and allocate records with `New()` keep them in the tree and then `Dispose()` when tree is cleared?

Comment: See I read that, but didnt get it - just noticed the OnFreeNode thing! :P

Answer (score 3):

The best way of storing data in VTV when using records as data holders is to store only pointers to the records while records themselves are stored separately in a list/array. This also corresponds to a virtual and MVC paradigm when visual component doesn't actually owns data.
IOW, the scheme of adding a record is:

- Allocate memory for the record (!) using AllocMem, New, ...
- Fill its fields
- Add it to the list/array
- Add new node to VTV with NodeData = PNewRecord

and the scheme of deleting a record is:

- Delete corresponding node from VTV
- Finalize record using Finalize (!) thus avoiding memory leaks with
  ref-counted fields
- Dispose allocated memory using FreeMem, Dispose, ...
- Delete item from list/array

Answer (score 0):

Yet another "I found the answer 2 minutes after I asked the question" - how humiliating... :(

Anyways, so - this can be acomplished by using CopyMemory, like this:

```
Procedure AddToTree(Person: TPerson);
Var
 Data: PPerson;
 Node: PVirtualNode;
Begin
 // add node
 Node := VT.AddChild(nil);
 // Get data of the node
 Data := VT.GetNodeData(Node);
 // Copy the Person stuff to the Node's data.
 CopyMemory(Data,@Person,SizeOf(Person));
End;
```

Comment: This is not a good idea - the record contains managed type (`Name: string`) and youre messing it up with `CopyMemory`.

Comment: Youre not supposed to copy a record like that - it will mess up string's refcount.

Comment: @Jeff You've just copied the pointer to a managed type and so taken a reference. You didn't increment the reference count. The compiler would do that for you but you went behind its back. Always a bad idea. But I don't know how VST is meant to work. I can't see how it can work at all if you are passing a void pointer to a record containing a string. Meh!

Comment: @David - I can tell you as far as I can see, its working perfectly fine. Gimme a few and I will try to fully test the concept

Comment: @Jeff If it works, youre just lucky (or unlucky, as it will bite you later)... do you use FastMM? Make some test where you change a local copy of the string you have copied in such a way - then you should get some "intresting results".

Comment: @Jeff: ain is perfectly right. One should not copy a record containing a string, interface, variant or dynamic array like that, since that way the reference count of these types is not updated, and it is freed too early. If you don't see any problems, you are lucky. You must use New() and Dispose() here, since these take care of such tasks. Really.

Comment: @David - No, I do not know what it is. ain - I tried that, worked perfectly! Changed a node's data.MyString;, I showed it, etc, all works fine :) Rudy - I am using D2010, so not sure. Not using New or Dispose.

Comment: I dont see what I am doing wrong - just making a copy of a populated record, and having my nodedata point to it, instead of assigning the data manually - that is what I am doing, right?

Comment: @Jeff Strings are managed reference types. A string field contains a pointer to the memory that holds the string. `SizeOf(s)` returns 4 no matter what is in the string `s`. If you don't let the compiler increment and decrement the reference count properly you will end up with stale pointers.

Comment: @David - So, by copying the memory, the compiler is unable to manage the new copy? Or something like that?

Comment: Jeff, to be a valid test, the `Name` field must not contain a string literal. Those are managed specially. Assign a value from a string-returning function, like IntToStr. You should get either an access violation or a memory leak.

Comment: @Rob - I did, I did `IntToStr(Random(100));` and it worked as well.

Comment: @Jeff What happens when you copy is that there are two references but only the compiler only knows about 1 of them. So long as you don't modify the string and you abandon the illicit reference first, you get away with it. Lucky you. In fact though, this is unlucky because when it does come back to bite you'll have a devil of a job tracking it down.

Comment: @David - Using Rob's answer, which is simpler :)